# StackExchange Redis Client StringSet return false?

Tags: azure, redis

We have been using StackExchange Redis .Net client for several months without issue.  Our logs indicate that StringSet returned false thousands of time over the course of an hour recently, but it is working as expected again.

I can't find what FALSE means anywhere.  I assume this means that the value was not put in cache, but if that is correct, how do I tell why?  The client is not throwing an exception.  Can someone show me the API Specification that describes the return value and how to troubleshoot?

We are running against Redis in Azure if that matters.

```
result = cache.StringSet(fullKey, value, GetCacheTime(cacheType));
if (!result)
{
    if (_logger != null)
    {
        _logger.LogError( "Failed to Set Cache");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We get hundreds of these a day in our service and I'm thinking perhaps the false response isn't an error but can't find any documentation on the .net api to verify this. It's spurious and had nothing to do with expiry time or memory/eviction policy

Comment: No. We still don't know why we are getting false.

Comment: Rather late but if you attempt to set the same key twice with a null value, the StringSet call returns false. I guess technically you should use KeyDelete() operation.

Answer (score 0):

http://redis.io/commands/set

> Simple string reply: OK if SET was executed correctly. Null reply: a
>   Null Bulk Reply is returned if the SET operation was not performed
>   becase the user specified the NX or XX option but the condition was
>   not met.

Though it looks like you are using SETEX (http://redis.io/commands/setex) are you setting a valid timespan as the third argument?

> SETEX is atomic, and can be reproduced by using the previous two
>   commands inside an MULTI / EXEC block. It is provided as a faster
>   alternative to the given sequence of operations, because this
>   operation is very common when Redis is used as a cache. An error is
>   returned when seconds is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ben.  The timespan should always be valid.  My  GetCacheTime function returns a static value based on what is being cached.  But I will add an additional check and logging here to be sure.  

It seems that we get large blocks of time (several minutes) where are logs are full of “false” returns from this method, and then no issues in the logs for days.  It is similar to how we sometimes have many Redis connection failures in a row, then nothing again for days.  Just the same, I would add a check to make sure the Timestamp is always valid. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an eviction policy and are you hitting memory caps?

Comment: According to our Azure portal we are under 50% memory utilization.  Issues has only come up once in the past 30 days, where previously we were getting once per week.  I expect Azure team may be making platform improvements?

Comment: Also perhaps test for null explicitly: == null rather than not testing which could be other values